# External Hard drive not showing up in Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I recovered a 160Gb hard drive (WD Scorpio Blue) from an **Apple TV** 1st generation.
I thought I could use it for storage.

But when I plug it in with an adapter, I don't see the drive show up in Disk Utility.

[image]

**Is there a way to diagnose this hard drive, maybe with Terminal, and understand why it doesn't mount?**

Comment: Does it spin up?  Does it show up as a USB device under System Information?

Comment: 2.5" drives *can* run from USB's 5v rail [unlike 3.5" drives which must have a 12v rail too] but I see an SATA power input there, which makes me wonder if the adapter itself is designed to use external SATA power. Does it work with other drives? Do you have the manual for the adaptor to check?

Comment: @Tetsujin I do not have the answer to these questions, no manual, but if you have another adapter you recommend I should use, let me know and I will get it and try it.